# Prove that $\int_C\frac{\cos(z)\mathrm dz}{\sin^2(z)}=0$ where C is any simple closed contour not passing through a zero of $\sin(z)$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is from a [practice exam](http://math.berkeley.edu/index.php?module=documents&JAS_DocumentManager_op=downloadFile&JAS_Document_id=3159) that we are working on, problem number 2. We were thinking first to use Cauchy-Goursat, but then the problem only says that the curve doesn't lie on the singularities of $\sin^2(z)$. They might still be interior to the curve. Is there another way to approach the problem using theorems we might know?

Edit: The question is : 
Prove that $$\int_C\frac{\cos(z)\mathrm dz}{\sin^2(z)}=0$$ where C is any simple closed contour not passing through a zero of $\sin(z)$.
Edit: I don't know about residues.

Comment: You should post the question also instead of linking to the pdf file.

Comment: okay. I will post the question as well.

Comment: Should that be $\sin^2(z)$ instead of $\sin^2(x)$?  $x$ hasn't appeared before.

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might notice that $\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin^2(z)}$ has an antiderivative (which any calculus student should be able to find) on the complement of its singularities.  You have probably seen a theorem that talks about contour integrals of a function that has an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about residues? If you do, notice that the integrand is a meromorphic function all of whose poles are double with zero residue. Using that, the result is immediate.

Comment: I don't know about residues actually.

Comment: @ILoveCake: well... it would help if you expanded the question with a description of what you do know :)